# Inserting a Row into a 2D Vector(vector of vectors)

Tags: c++, vector

Relatively new to the C++ scene.  Anyways, I have a list:

> 1 5 6
>       3 1 2
>       5 3 4 7
>       6 2
>       7 3

I am attempting to fill out the numbers that are missing (in this case, 2 and 4).  This list is being inputted as a vector of vectors.  That's working fine.  My function to insert numbers where they need to be is not.  This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector< vector<int> > vec1;

vector<int> tempVec;


string str = "";
stringstream ss;
int temp = 0;

ifstream iFile;
//  iFile.open("E:\\COMP 220\\SCC sample input.txt");
iFile.open("E:\\SCC sample input2.txt");


if (iFile.is_open()) //Inputs file
{
    cout << "File is open!\n";

    getline(iFile, str);
    while (!iFile.eof())
    {
        int z = 0;
        stringstream ss(str);
        while (ss >> temp)
        {
            tempVec.push_back(temp);
            cout << tempVec[z] << " ";
            z++;
        }
        vec1.push_back(tempVec);
        cout << endl;
        tempVec.clear();
        getline(iFile, str);
    }
}

int count = 0;
while (count < vec1.size() - 1)
{
    if (vec1[count][0] != vec1[count + 1][0] - 1)
    {
        tempVec.clear();
        tempVec.push_back(vec1[count][0] + 1);
        vec1.insert(count, tempVec);
    }
    else
        count++;
}

return 0;
}
```

When finished, I was hoping the code would resemble:

> 1 5 6
>   2
>   3 1 2
>   4
>   5 3 4 7
>   6 2
>   7 3

Any ideas?  The current problem is a compiler error with:
vec1.insert(count, tempVec);

Comment: It's giving me a compiler error with the "vec1.insert(count, tempVec);" but I don't know why.

Comment: you'll have to provide a [mcve]

Comment: what is really not logical is the `clear` followed by `push_back` in a loop...

Comment: the "clear" is to clear tempVec because I use it earlier for a different reason, and then to clear it before every use because I'm just inserting one number.  The loop is to iterate down the problem.

Comment: I'll try to put something together that can run, just a moment.

Comment: Look at the documentation for [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) - this method uses an interface based on iterators, not indices.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury Ah, that's a little confusing.  Indices as in index, right?  But count is just an integer.  How would I write it with an iterator?

Comment: Good job on avoiding the usual `while (!iFile.eof())` bug, but can I talk you into `while (getline(iFile, str))`? Less code repetition, catches whole families of other errors, and easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 2):

You get the compiler error since `count` is an integer, and  [std::vector::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)'s first parameter is an iterator, not an integer.

To get to a certain position in a vector using an iterator, use the `vector::begin()` iterator and add on the position:

So this:

```
vec1.insert(count, tempVec);
```

should be

```
vec1.insert(vec1.begin() + count, tempVec);
```

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed that particular problem very nicely.